# override a DNS server for a single DNS mapping on windows machine

Tags: windows, networking, dns, routes, active-directory

I've got a single DNS entry which I want to map to an external IP address (the ip represent an active directory server running on amazon cloud). Unfortunately, the DNS server used in my organisation has different mapping and it send this URL to internal address (local network) and I don't have permissions to change it for all users.

So I've manually change this DNS entry in my local machine. However, every once in a while, it gets updated by the DNS server.

I tried disabling that updates with a Group Policy, but with no help.

Is there any way to permanently set this DNS mapping either locally (preferable) or in the DNS server for my machine only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your host file.

In windows:

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

In Mac:

```
/etc/hosts
```

In Linux

```
/etc/hosts
```

Add your server there

```
123.123.123.123 domain.com
```

Your host file have precedence over the DNS query and is much faster.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, does this ensure that no DNS server I'm connected to, will override the mapping ?

Comment: nop. give it a shot. Host file have precedence if is not found on the host file then it will query a DNS server.

Comment: Great, it seems to be working... But do you know if it's possible to also change this mapping in the dns itself ... because now I see that I need this mapping for all clients. Perhaps do you know how to change a single record of dns in that runs on Windows Server 2019 ?

Comment: Well is kind of a complicated. If you have configured only 1 DNS server that's the way to go, create a new record on the Windows DNS server and done. The issue is if you are using multiple DNS servers like your ISP, google or any other open DNS service then It will make the request to the first and second depending on the response time etc. I am pointing this out because if you make the entry on the DNS that you manage you may still be getting your public ip instead of the internal one.

Comment: Thanks for help, since I'm newbie at Windows Server, perhaps you can refer my to any documentation for how 2 create new record on the windows dns server ? Thanks again !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/add-a-host--a--resource-record-to-corporate-dns-for-a-federation-server  This may help you !